# Why does this specific $\delta$ imply a failure of $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$? (trouble in understanding continuity proof)

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

I'm having a bit of trouble with a the proof in Ross' Elementary Analysis. The theorem is the $\epsilon-\delta$ one. Theorem: Let $f$ be continuous at $x_0$ in $dom(f)$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>o$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x \in dom(f)$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ $(1)$.

My issue with the proof is in the forward direction. He writes:

"Now assume $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, but $(1)$ fails. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that the implication $x\in dom(f)$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ failed for each $\delta>0$ . In particular, the implication $x\in dom(f)$ and $|x-x_0|<\frac{1}{n}$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ fails for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n$ in $dom(f)$ such that $|x_n-x_0|< \frac{1}{n}$ and yet $|f(x_0)-f(x_n)|\ge \epsilon$.""

In his example, where he chose $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$, I am failing to see how that particular choice of delta implies $|f(x_0)-f(x_n)|\ge\epsilon$. Is it just by assumption? Or is there another reason involved?

Comment: well no, whats the meaning of $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ failing?

Comment: That $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge \epsilon$ right? How do I know for that specific $\delta$, it insures $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears he is assuming $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon$ fails for each natural. Or to put it another way $|f(x_0) - f(x_n)| \ge \epsilon$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

His choice of delta is not special in any interesting way, and it's not that particular choice of delta that makes the condition for continuity fail. That delta is just one of the many positive deltas that make the condition fail for a particular epsilon. He assumes that the function is continuous but the condition for continuity fails for *any* positive delta, that is **for each** $δ>0$, and $|x−x0|<δ$, we would have  $|f(x0)−f(xn)|≥ϵ$ for some particular epsilon. So choosing $δ=1/n$ is really just an example, not anything that adds value to his argument. He is choosing a delta that allows us to get as close to zero as possible, but still greater than zero. That's why he defines delta like that.